# A little help with this xPath?

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I am getting some info from an RSS.

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
$dom->load('http://www.myrss.com');
libxml_clear_errors();

$xPath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$links = $xPath->query('xxxxx');
foreach($links as $link) {
    printf("%s \n", $link->nodeValue);
}
?>
```

I have managed to get the TITLE, LINK and DESCRIPTION with `//item/title` and so on, howver I want to get the text content and image of description seperated.

As I can see through page source using firefox this is the code I see for image and the content. Both are in `<description></description>`

**IMAGE**

```
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;"><a href="LINK TO IMAGE" imageanchor="1" 
style="clear: left; float: left; margin-bottom: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img border="0" height="192" 
src="LINK TO IMAGE" width="320" /></a></div>
```

**CONTENT TEXT**

```
<span class="Apple-style-span" style="font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;"> CONTENT TEXT IS HERE </span>
```

What xPath should I use to get those data? Thank you

Comment: Do note that you have no elements to selects but just a big **text node**. Atom correctly handle embedded XML vocabulary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is what it looks like and the content is HTML-encoded, you can't do it in one step. You must retrieve every description text and parse into its own DOM *(unless you want to resort to regex, which I would strongly discourage)*.

When in doubt, you can pass it through [Tidy](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) before. `DOMDocument` has `loadHTML()`, which is pretty resilient, but it is not guaranteed that it can load *any* HTML.

```
// beware, this is untested. it should give you an idea, though.

$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);

$dom->load('http://www.myrss.com');
libxml_clear_errors();

$xPath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$items = $xPath->query('/rss/channel/item');

foreach($items as $item) {
    $descr = $xPath->query('./description', $item);
    // there should be at most one, but foreach gracefully
    // handles the case where there is no <description>
    foreach ($descr as $d) {
        $temp_dom = new DOMDocument();
        $temp_dom->loadHTML( $d->nodeValue );   // error handling/Tidy here!

        $temp_xpath = new DOMXPath($temp_dom);

        $img = $temp_xpath->query('//img');
        $txt = $temp_xpath->query('//span[@class="Apple-style-span"]');

        // now do something with $img and $txt
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks I think this is a piece of code that would help me a lot! I am testing it right now but I dont managed it to display something yet. Should I replace $items = $xPath->query('/channel/item'); with something ?

Comment: @JBCurious: Well, it depends on what your RSS looks like, the `/channel/item` was just a guess. Maybe you also have to register a default namespace first with [`registerNamespace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.registernamespace.php). BTW: Once you get it working you can propose an edit to my answer. I will approve it as soon as I see it.

Comment: Ok then! I will get in contact with you the sooner. The rss link is http://feeds.feedburner.com/blogspot/hyMBI just in case

Comment: @JBCurious: Looks like there is no namespace involved and the XPath `/rss/channel/item` should fetch you what you want. I'll fix my answer. Also, keep an eye on UTF-8 issues, I'm not entirely certain how well PHP handles the Greek letters.

Comment: I got this : Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMNodeList could not be converted to string....

Comment: @JBCurious: On which line? If I should help you, please don't make me guess.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I tried to echo $img and $txt at the place that the comment says so... abd the error is there. If i remove the echo the code runs fine.

Comment: @JBCurious: You can't echo a complex object (`DOMXPath::query()` returns a node list, and that is not printable). Use a foreach loop to iterate the result and do something with the DOMNode objects in it.

Comment: You mean this foreach ($img as $imgs) { echo $imgs; } just below of $img = $temp_xpath->query('//img');

My purpose is to save them as variables or print them

Comment: @JBCurious: Please also have a look into the documentation. Look what object types you are dealing with (DONNodeList, DOMNode) and what methods they provide. You can't just simply echo any object.

Comment: Tomalak I admit it you helped me a lot. I searched and found another answer of yours, saying that you can do it with foreach ($img as $imgs) {  echo $imgs->nodeValue; }
But it doesnt do the trick. Here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548744/php-xpath-question

Comment: @JBCurious: It doesn't do the trick because it should be `foreach ($img as $imgs) { echo $img->getAttribute('src'); }`, for example. In no case it could be `echo $imgs->nodeValue` because, if at all, it is `$img->nodeValue`.

Comment: Man you are perfect!! Hopefully I end with this question with the CONTENT TEXT. I tried `foreach ($txt as $txts) { echo $txt->items(0)->nodeValue; }` with no result... I assume you this is my last one and sorry for my questions but I am kind new in DOM. I tried it with regex with not 100% results :)

Comment: @JBCurious: Have you tried `echo $txts->textContent;`? `$txts` is the `DOMNode` object here and `$txt` is the `DOMNodeList` - choosing more intuitive variable names would help. Also look at [`DOMDocument::saveHTML()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php), this might be useful to find more specific XPath expressions if you need them.

Answer (score 0):

Your code didn't format correctly so it would be hard for others to work on it.

However, the interactive tool here: http://www.bubasoft.net/  (XPath Builder) is very helpful when constructing XPath queries.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the content is encoded/escaped so you can't query it with Xpath as it isn't HTML/XML. [Take at htmlentities and html_entity_decode](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

You should extract the content, convert it to HTML/XML en load it into a DOM Document separately. Then you can query it using Xpath.