# Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string

Tags: php, xml-parsing, domdocument

I try to parse an XML rss flux. Actually, an error is thrown:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string in ...
```

I want to get the value "test" of the tag "link"

Here is my code :

```
//check if url contents xml
            $content = file_get_contents($flux);

            $xml = new DOMDocument;
            $xml->loadXML($content);

            //get the link
            $link = $xml->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0);

            echo $link;
```

Here is the flux :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15" ?>
<rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>test</title>
        <link>http://test.fr</link>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Anyone can help me ?

Comment: possible help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548744/php-xpath-question

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`$link` is an object which can not be converted to string ([some objects can](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.tostring)).

To see which object it is, use `var_dump($link);`. I assume it's a [`DOMElement`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php), see the link for all properties and methods it has to offer, e.g.

```
echo $link->tagName;
```

or

```
echo $link->textContent;
```

Comment: tagName returns "link" not "test". Thank you anyway