# CURL data in array

Tags: php, curl

I am using cURL to fetch data from another site into my application. I am getting the data in exactly the same format as it is displayed on the browser.

What I need is to get the data in a form of an array.

I even tried using `file_get_contents`, but it also doesn't gives me the data in array (as it outputs in array).

Comment: show us how your data Looks like and show us your CURL code...

Comment: We're good, but we're not psychic. We can't read your mind to see how this data looks.

Comment: This is my code:$url='bpwr.XXX.com:8026?DataDate=2012-11-05';curl_setopt($ch,CURL…); curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout); $data = curl_exec($ch); print_r($data); curl_close($ch);

Comment: This gives me the whole screen, whereas my requirement to get just the content of the page in the form of the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to take the cookie data and the location of a header, I use this code, hope this help.

You can try with any other information that the header can give you.

```
...
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$var = explode("\n", $result);
$header = array();

foreach( $var as $row ) {
    if( strpos( strtolower($row), "set-cookie: " ) !== false ) {
        $header['set-cookie'] = str_ireplace("Set-Cookie: ", "", $row);
    } else if( strpos( strtolower($row), "location: " ) !== false ) {
        $header['location'] = str_ireplace("Location: ", "", $row);
    }
}
```

**PS:** I was mistaken, i believed that it was about the Header not the HTML content.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the xpath.
check it on the [PHP & xPath Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548744/php-xpath-question) or try search with xpath.

Comment: This is my code:$url='http://bpwr.XXX.com:8026?DataDate=2012-11-05';curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
      $data = curl_exec($ch); print_r($data); curl_close($ch);

Comment: This gives me the whole screen, whereas my requirement to get just the content of the page in the form of the array.

Comment: Have you ever used xpath? It will load you whole html and you can fetch whatever element you have required from that html.